# Getting angle from current position and next position

Tags: 2d, mathematics

I am using pathfinding to move a train along rails, but I need the train to rotate. I have the next intended position and the current position at my disposal, how would I go about this? Pseudocode will do as an answer since I am using a specialized programming language for the engine that I use.

Comment: You mean the angle of intersection between two lines? (first line is previews point and current, second line is current point and next point)

Comment: Are you looking for [the Atan2 function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2), that converts a direction vector to a heading angle?

Answer (score 0):

This is a prototype lookat function , in which an object forward will point towards a defined position. In your case the Up vector can be set to fixed value since the object does not need to pitch up or down.
Hope this helps

```
  //your object
     glm::vec3 obPos = glm::vec3(sceneEntity->getPostion().x(),sceneEntity->getPostion().y(),sceneEntity->getPostion().z());
            
    //Next positon
    glm::vec3 tarPo = glm::vec3(ptl.x(),ptl.y(),ptl.z());
    
            glm::vec3 delta = tarPo - obPos;//targetPosition-objectPosition
            glm::vec3 up;
            glm::vec3 dir(glm::normalize(delta));
    
            if(abs(dir.x) < 0.00001 && abs(dir.z) < 0.00001){
                if(dir.y > 0)
                    up = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0); //if direction points in +y
                else
                    up = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); //if direction points in -y
            } else {
                up = glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); //y-axis is the general up
            }
            up = glm::normalize(up);
            glm::vec3 right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(up,dir));
            //up = glm::normalize(glm::cross(dir, right));
    
            rotationMatrix *= glm::mat4(right.x, right.y, right.z, 0.0f,
                                        up.x, up.y, up.z, 0.0f,
                                        dir.x, dir.y, dir.z, 0.0f,
                                        obPos.x, obPos.y, obPos.z, 1.0f);
```

Comment: I'm interested as to why you recalculate the `up` direction after calculating the `right` direction using the `up` and `dir` directions

Comment: Good catch , this was part of my algo tools code , I don't remember exactly why,  but knowing me , i might have put it there to check if the up vector coming out is the same as what i put in , in a way validating that step(put a break point there and validate) , whiteout having to do the math on paper for each iteration with update values..   I should have commented it out . Thanks